# Facebook Graph php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get basic informations from an facebook page with this code:

```
 <?php
    $fb = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/exemplename", "rb");
    $fb_array=json_decode($fb,true);
    echo $fb_array['id'];
    echo $fb_array['name'];
    echo $fb_array['picture'];
    ?>
```

This work perfect on xampp local server but when I upload on webserver it just show a blank page. Anyone knows the reason why it doesn't work on webserver ?

Comment: Check your error logs for the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Does your remote server allow you to fetch data via remote URLs? See the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) configuration directive in your `php.ini`. If not and if you can't change the configuration you have to refactor your code to use [`ext/curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (if installed).